# Converting date and ordering a data frame?

Tags: r, date

I added my data below. I would like to convert ind column'class as date ( which is a factor right now). Also, I want to order my data frame based on month, which will start from january and end in december. Anyone can help me please?

```
structure(list(values = c(36L, 36L, 23L, 38L, 249L, 31L, 20L, 
28L, 36L, 35L, 41L, 43L), ind = structure(1:12, .Label = c("April", 
"August", "December", "February", "January", "July", "June", 
"March", "May", "November", "October", "September"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("values", 
"ind"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of 15410273

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't actually want dates (because dates include year and day as well as months, and all you have are months):

```
foo$ind <- factor(foo$ind, levels = month.name)
foo <- foo[order(foo$ind), ]
foo
   values       ind
5     249   January
4      38  February
8      28     March
1      36     April
9      36       May
7      20      June
6      31      July
2      36    August
12     43 September
11     41   October
10     35  November
3      23  December
```

Comment: which is what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo$ind <- as.Date(paste("2014", "1", foo$ind), format = "%Y %d %b")
foo[order(foo$ind),]
##    values        ind
## 5     249 2014-01-01
## 4      38 2014-02-01
## 8      28 2014-03-01
## 1      36 2014-04-01
## 9      36 2014-05-01
## 7      20 2014-06-01
## 6      31 2014-07-01
## 2      36 2014-08-01
## 12     43 2014-09-01
## 11     41 2014-10-01
## 10     35 2014-11-01
## 3      23 2014-12-01
```